# Raffle Odds for 1:125000, 3 winners, bought 5 tickets

Tags: probability

If I bought 5 raffle tickets with a 1:125000 odds rating- what are my odds at winning if there are 3 winners, with winning tickets NOT returned to the bucket each time?

Answer (score 1):

Let $N$ be the total number of tickets (in your case $N=125000$)

There are $\binom{N}{3}$ ways in which the $3$ winning tickets can be chosen.

There are $\binom{N-5}{3}$ ways in which the $3$ winning tickets can be chosen so none of your tickets are selected.

Hence the probability you lose is:

$$\frac{\binom{N-5}{3}}{\binom{N}{3}}=\frac{(N-5)(N-6)(N-7)}{N(N-1)(N-2)}$$

So the probability you have at least one winning ticket is $1-\frac{(N-5)(N-6)(N-7)}{N(N-1)(N-2)}$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. How are the odds effected by purchasing 5 tickets? The total number of tickets for sale is 375000. Since there are 3 winners, the company lists the odds as 1:125000. I don't know how many tickets I will have purchased by the time the drawing is done, but currently I have 5. :) Have a great weekend!!! Thanks again. :)

Comment: Oh I see, my bad. Ill modify the answer